# Squishing commits that are a few months apart

Tags: git, github

I've got a git branch that I've been working on periodically.  It's now ready to go to github and a pull request opened.

Doing this however, I'll have eight or ten commits that stretch over several months.  I personally don't mind that but the reviewers like to have us squish commits as often as possible.

Personally I've only ever squished consecutive commits, amending messages and so on.  Is there a good way to squish in a case like this, where the commits are non-consecutive and interleaved with those from periodic merges from master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout a new branch, cherry-pick the relevant commits onto that branch (resolving merge conflicts as necessary), and then squash those (now consecutive) commits into one.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tried this, and there may well be a more elegant approach.